# @walletconnect/modal Cannot find module 'packages/modal-core/dist/_types/src/controllers/ModalCtrl' or its corresponding type declarations, Angular 16

Tags: angular, decentralized-applications, wallet-connect

Iam trying to migrate Walletconnect v1 to v2 in my Angular dapp but i have issues with two specific imports in @walletconnect/modal

```
import("packages/modal-core/dist/_types/src/controllers/ModalCtrl").OpenOptions
import("packages/modal-core/dist/_types/src/types/controllerTypes").ModalCtrlState
```

error message is:
`Cannot find module 'packages/modal-core/dist/_types/src/controllers/ModalCtrl' or its corresponding type declarations.`

[error in node_modules/@walletconnect/modal/dist/_types/src/client.d.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUJpm.png)

There is packages folder in modal repository ([here](https://github.com/walletconnect/modal)), however when i download package via npm the structure of files is somewhat different:
[structure of files in node_modules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/faUGK.png)
That is why it cannot find the path. I dont know if iam doing something wrong or its bug on walletconnect side.

Iam using:

```
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1601.4
@angular-devkit/build-angular   16.1.4
@angular-devkit/core            16.1.4
@angular-devkit/schematics      16.1.4
@angular/cli                    16.1.4
@schematics/angular             16.1.4
ng-packagr                      16.1.0
rxjs                            7.8.1
typescript                      5.1.6

Angular CLI: 16.1.4
Node: 19.6.0
Package Manager: npm 9.4.0
```

and i have latest @walletconnect packages:

```
"@walletconnect/ethereum-provider": "^2.9.0",
"@walletconnect/modal": "^2.6.0",
```

When i change the imports to:
`import("../../../../modal-core/dist/_types/src/controllers/ModalCtrl").OpenOptions`
or change the type to
`any`
everything works (to do that i need to create fork of their repository etc...)

Comment: [link to github discussion](https://github.com/WalletConnect/web3modal/issues/1211),
response from wc was 'I think only way around this will be to set skipLibCheck option in your tsconfig.' which is also a solution so far

Answer (score 0):

import("@walletconnect/modalcore/dist/_types/src/controllers/ModalCtrl").OpenOptions,

import("@walletconnect/modalcore/dist/_types/src/types/controllerTypes").ModalCtrlState.

This is working for me in angular 16.0.0